# Sent email converts unicode characters into mojibake

Tags: powershell, email, unicode, mojibake

I have a mail script sending automated messages to agents about tickets, but Swedish extended characters are being garbled in the script. The text is garbled even when I send it to console instead of emailing.

My research indicates that strings in PowerShell are in UTF16, so I expected things to be preserved... alas, mojibake.

I started with Net.Mail.SmtpClient and that didn't work. I switched to Send-MailMessage because of the -Encoding parameter, but that doesn't change anything for me. I've messed around with the $OutputEncoding variable in case that had something to do with something, but no luck.

*So, for example* (assuming this doesn't get mangled here either):
The extended characters from the Sweedish alphabet are `ÅÄÖåäö`
And they get rendered as `Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶`

```
#$encod = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
$encod = ([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode);
$OutputEncoding = $encod;

[string]$message = 'ÅÄÖåäö';
$emailFrom = "Example <EXAMPLE@SAMPLE.COM>";
$emailTo = "Test <TEST@SAMPLE.COM)";
$subject="Långtidsspara";
$smtpserver="smtp.SAMPLE.COM";

#$smtp=New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer);
#$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message) ;
Send-MailMessage -Body $message -Encoding $encod -From $emailFrom -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Subject $subject -To $emailTo
```

Edited to add: Previously when I was trying the Net.Mail.SmtpClient() I was doing the following:

```
$smtp=New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer);
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message);
```

but I couldn't find a way to adjust the encoding.

EDIT 2: thanks to @RemyLebeau I have tried setting the message up as a MailMessage object and using SmtpClient to send that, but no change in behavior.

```
$smtp=New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer);
$mail=New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message);
$mail.BodyEncoding = $encod;
$mail.HeadersEncoding = $encod;
$mail.SubjectEncoding = $encod;
$mail.BodyTransferEncoding = [System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::EightBit;
$smtp.SendMailAsync($mail);
```

EDIT 3: After correcting from UTF16 to UTF8, my email headers say the following

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?SW5zcGVsbmluZ3NkYXRhIChMw4PCpW5ndGlkc3NwYXJhKQ==?=
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

But it's all still garbled. I've got Outlook 365 here, but I get emails from Europe all the time, including previous emails from a customer with Å in their name, and Outlook seems to cope?

Comment: `Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `ÅÄÖåäö` being interpreted as Latin1 instead of UTF-8. Either the receiver is buggy and ignoring the email's actual charset, or your email is not specifying its charset correctly. Hard to say since you did you show the actual email data that is being transmitted. I don't know how Powershell works, but if you use `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to send a `Net.Mail.MailMessage` object, the object has `HeadersEncoding`, `SubjectEncoding`, `BodyEncoding`, and `BodyTransferEncoding` properties. You really should be using UTF-8 for everything

Comment: Why are you using `$OutputEncoding`? That has no effect on the message.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Desperately trying to find everything related to encoding, since all the things that seemed logical weren't working.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, using UTF-8 for everything is the goal, but so far I haven't managed to get it to use UTF-8 for *anything*. That said, I'd never seen hide-nor-hair about MailMessage objects

Comment: Regarding "did not show the actual email data that is being transmitted", I certainly thought I had. What am I not showing?

Comment: That subject looks like base64

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: it is base64.  That is how MIME encodes non-ASCII data in headers (see [RFC 2047](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047))

Comment: @EmilySmirle: The `Subject` you showed (you didn't show the complete email) is the RFC 2047 encoded form of `Inspelningsdata (LÃ¥ngtidsspara)`, which is different than `Långtidsspara` that you originally showed. It looks like your input data is getting **double**-encoded to UTF-8 (encoded to UTF-8 once, then the resulting octets encoded to UTF-8 again, which is wrong) before the resulting octets are  encoded in base64.

Comment: @EmilySmirle: As for Outlook, there are several ways to encode non-ASCII data in emails, MIME being the most popular and portable, but Outlook's decoder is more flexible, it can cope with a variety of (mis)encodings.